How can you remove an input via RBF with Bitcoin Core?
I have an original transaction with two inputs and want to replace it with a transaction that has only one of the two inputs.
Original transaction spending from two addresses:
input 1: 0,5 btc  ⇒  output 1: 0.99 btc  
input 2: 0,5 btc

Is it possible to replace this transaction by this one:
input 1: 0,5 btc  ⇒  output 1: 0,49 btc

If that is possible, then how can you do that using Bitcoin Core?

Hi Alice, I edited your post to improve the formatting and included a sentence to describe what I understood your question to be. Please feel free to further edit or rollback if you feel that it doesn’t match your intent.
